# Prevent hotlinking on Amazon S3 while allowing mobile app

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to prevent hotlinking of my images on S3 (which I can easily find how to do on Google or StackOverflow), but I would also like to allow my mobile app to request images.

Is there a way to allow my app to directly GET an S3 resource (without using a proxy authorized server), maybe using a specific HTTP header, while also disabling hotlinking from other websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [AWS SDK for Android](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforandroid/) to access the files from your mobile application. You will need to have a mechanism for delivering the credentials to the mobile device, such as [an anonymous Token Vending Machine](http://aws.amazon.com/code/8872061742402990).

If you already have a server backend for your app you could also use this server to generate presigned URLs that would be accessed by your application. These presigned URLs could be time bound to limit the potential for extraction by an attacker.